# RavenDb 4: Check if a string of an array of strings exists in different array of strings

Tags: linq, ravendb, ravendb4

I am trying to filter my activities based on user roles. The manager is only allowed to see the activities that contain the role `Manager`. See below for more information.

Data:

```
var user = new User
{
    Roles = [
        "Manager"
    ]   
}

var activities = new List<Activity>
{
    new Activity
    {
        Description = "My First Activity",
        Roles = [
            "Admin",
            "Manager"
        ]
    },  
    new Activity
    {
        Description = "My Second Activity",
        Roles = [
            "Admin"
        ]
    },  
    new Activity
    {
        Description = "My Third Activity",
        Roles = [
            "Manager",
            "Client"
        ]
    },
}
```

Query that filters the activity

```
 var filtered = await context.Query<Activity>()
                    .Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => user.Roles.Contains(y)))
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Expected result of filtered:

```
[
    {
        new Activity
        {
            Description = "My First Activity",
            Roles = [
                "Admin",
                "Manager"
            ]
        }
        new Activity
        {
            Description = "My Third Activity",
            Roles = [
                "Manager",
                "Client"
            ]
        },
    }
]
```

Error from query

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Can't extract value from expression of type: Parameter
```

I am getting an error, so obviously I am doing something wrong. Is this the correct way or is there something better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires RavenDB to do computation during query, try this, instead:

`.Where(x => x.Roles.In(user.Roles))` (might need to add a using statement for the `In` extension method, `Raven.Client.Linq`, IIRC).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!